# Java daylight saving seems to be wrong

Tags: java, datetime, dst

I've been facing some issues with timezone with Java since yesterday (21/10/2018). Looks like java is considering that daylight saving have taken place in Brazil but it hasn't.

I created the following test to be sure

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ZonedDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.now().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
    System.out.println(dateTime);

    ZonedDateTime saoPaulo = dateTime.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("America/Sao_Paulo"));
    ZonedDateTime cuiba = dateTime.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("America/Cuiaba"));
    ZonedDateTime rightTime = dateTime.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("GMT-4"));
    System.out.println(saoPaulo);
    System.out.println(cuiba);
    System.out.println(rightTime);
}
```

That gave the following output

```
    2018-10-22T09:55:34.473-02:00[America/Sao_Paulo]
    2018-10-22T09:55:34.473-02:00[America/Sao_Paulo]
    2018-10-22T08:55:34.473-03:00[America/Cuiaba]
    2018-10-22T07:55:34.473-04:00[GMT-04:00]
```

That's wrong as the current timezone to São Paulo should be -03 and America/Cuiaba should be -04

Anyone knows what's the source of the timezone information on Java? There is something I can do on my side to fix that? I know that I can fix it by setting a fixed GMT offset but I'm not fond of it.

Comment: See https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tzdata-versions-138805.html (We can't tell which version of Java you've got etc.)

Comment: Thank you @JonSkeet. That link really helped me out

Answer (score 1):

The link posted by Jon Skeet helped me to solve my issue. Oracle had updated the daylight savings information on latest releases. After updating JDK version, it's working as expected.

```
    2018-10-22T09:19:31.761-03:00[America/Sao_Paulo]
    2018-10-22T09:19:31.761-03:00[America/Sao_Paulo]
    2018-10-22T08:19:31.761-04:00[America/Cuiaba]
    2018-10-22T08:19:31.761-04:00[GMT-04:00]
```

Answer (score 0):

Bug fix is ​​not available... small workaround.

```
DateTimeFormatter DT_FORMAT = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss XXX");
int hours   = (int) ((TimeZone.getDefault().getRawOffset() / (1000*60*60)) % 24);
String strGMT = "GMT" + ( hours<0 ? hours : "+"+hours );
DT_FORMAT.format(ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(value, ZoneId.of(ZoneIdUtils.getZoneId())))
```