# Oracle Timezone - Brazil 2018 change

Tags: oracle, timezone, timezone-offset

Similar to the issue described in the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52928931/java-daylight-daylight-saving-seems-to-be-wrong):

But for Oracle database itself.

There's a database running on machine whose timezone/clock is set to *Brazil/East/Brasilia/SaoPaulo time*. We use this query to get the database clock and convert it to *GMT*:

```
SELECT to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') AS MY_SYSDATE
, TO_CHAR(FROM_TZ (CAST (SYSDATE AS TIMESTAMP), 'America/Sao_Paulo') AT TIME ZONE 'GMT'
, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') as gmt_brazil_east
, TO_CHAR(FROM_TZ (CAST (SYSDATE AS TIMESTAMP), 'Etc/GMT+3') AT TIME ZONE 'GMT', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') as gmt_03
FROM DUAL
WHERE 1=1
;
```

Every since this past weekend, the value for the field "gmt_brazil_east" is wrong... I suspect because our Oracle hasn't been updated to reflect the recent change regarding when Brazil changes daylight-savings... Described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time_in_Brazil):

Though our database version is recent, it is *Oracle Database 12c Standard Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production*

I tried finding info on this similar to the Java-related post above, but could not... Does anyone know where I can find which version/patch of Oracle has this change to Brazil timezone corrected?

Comment: Have a look at this: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NLSPG/ch4datetime.htm#NLSPG260

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't know if you have access to Oracle Support, but there is a patch to DSTv32 for Oracle 11.2.0.3.0 until 18.3 available.
Have a look here [Brazil to Start DST on November From 2018 Onwards- Impact on Oracle RDBMS (Doc ID 2331560.1)](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocContentDisplay?id=2331560.1)